# Why layer number in keras does not start from 1 after deleting and recreating model?

Tags: python, keras

I am new to keras, I am trying to create a CNN model. I created one sequential model as follows-

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (5, 5), activation='relu', input_shape=(150, 150, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
print(model.summary())
```

I get the summary as follows-

> ---
>
> ```
> Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
> =================================================================
> conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 146, 146, 32)      2432      
> _________________________________________________________________
> max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 73, 73, 32)        0         
> _________________________________________________________________
> conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 71, 71, 64)        18496     
> _________________________________________________________________
> max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 35, 35, 64)        0         
> _________________________________________________________________
> conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 33, 33, 64)        36928     
> _________________________________________________________________
> max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 16, 16, 64)        0         
> =================================================================
> Total params: 57,856
> Trainable params: 57,856
> Non-trainable params: 0
> _________________________________________________________________
> ```

After this, I delete the model using `del model` and again create it using above code, I get the summary as follows-

> ---
>
> ```
> Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
> =================================================================
> conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 146, 146, 32)      2432      
> _________________________________________________________________
> max_pooling2d_4 (MaxPooling2 (None, 73, 73, 32)        0         
> _________________________________________________________________
> conv2d_5 (Conv2D)            (None, 71, 71, 64)        18496     
> _________________________________________________________________
> max_pooling2d_5 (MaxPooling2 (None, 35, 35, 64)        0         
> _________________________________________________________________
> conv2d_6 (Conv2D)            (None, 33, 33, 64)        36928     
> _________________________________________________________________
> max_pooling2d_6 (MaxPooling2 (None, 16, 16, 64)        0         
> =================================================================
> Total params: 57,856
> Trainable params: 57,856
> Non-trainable params: 0
> _________________________________________________________________
> ```

So, why is this summary showing layer numbering from **conv2d_4**, it should be from **conv2d_1**?

Even if I create another model-

```
model_2 = models.Sequential()
model_2.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (5, 5), activation='relu', input_shape=(150, 150, 3)))
model_2.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))
model_2.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model_2.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model_2.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model_2.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
print(model_2.summary())
```

I get numbering starting after the final layer number of previous model-

> ---
>
> ```
> Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
> =================================================================
> conv2d_7 (Conv2D)            (None, 146, 146, 32)      2432      
> _________________________________________________________________
> max_pooling2d_7 (MaxPooling2 (None, 73, 73, 32)        0         
> _________________________________________________________________
> conv2d_8 (Conv2D)            (None, 71, 71, 64)        18496     
> _________________________________________________________________
> max_pooling2d_8 (MaxPooling2 (None, 35, 35, 64)        0         
> _________________________________________________________________
> conv2d_9 (Conv2D)            (None, 33, 33, 64)        36928     
> _________________________________________________________________
> max_pooling2d_9 (MaxPooling2 (None, 16, 16, 64)        0         
> =================================================================
> Total params: 57,856
> Trainable params: 57,856
> Non-trainable params: 0
> _________________________________________________________________
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what backend you are using:

You can see (https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L132):

```
name = _to_snake_case(prefix) + '_' + str(K.get_uid(prefix))
```

And Keras does not reset the uids on `del model`. When using the tensorflow backend Keras does reset the uids though on `clear_session()`.